# Retrieving boolean values of System Properties (Terminal commands)

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line

I am familiar with the state changes to system properties (such as displaying hidden files) using Terminal commands including: `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` to make the any hidden files become visible.

But what is the command for showing the **current state/status** of this (and similar) properties, to retrieve what it is set to, without changing the value?

During my initial tinkering, I've already trying appending a `STATUS` value in place of the `YES` or `NO` option; without any luck.

I'm certain there must be a command that returns the current state of the boolean or enumerated type's property, such that entering a variation of the above-mentioned command (to show hidden files) will not perform any changes but rather return the current setting i.e. `YES` or `NO`.

I am out of ideas and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` qualifier shows the value:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 1

$ defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles
1

$ defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 0

$ defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles
0
```

The `man defaults` Terminal command gives a wealth of information.

Comment: I don't see how, because all I removed was the personal prompt - "family-imac ~ dude" portion.

Comment: Easy fix.... the indenting to get the full code formatting must have word wrapped it.